# xlookup to differentiate value "x" and value "x o" and return max date

Tags: excel, formula, xlookup

I've an excel spread sheet that is looking through a list of names.  Many repeat.
But to differentiate what a person has done, a " o" is added after there name at points.

I need the max date of the "name o".

This formula works (kind of):

```
=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(MAX(tblSchedule[Date]),(tblSchedule[Public Speaker]=[@Name]&" o")*tblSchedule[Date],tblSchedule[Date],"",-1,1),"")
```

But it also returns the oldest date for any 0(false) result and I can't seem to clean that up.
[image]

This is the table it is looking at:

[image]

Notice how the name Cr did find oldest Last Home date and Last Out date, but while the others had no " o", it returned the oldest date on the list (All 2/5/23).

*I have probably answered my questions somewhere, but I keep missing it.*

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: I could not find a way to do this with xlookup, but ended up using MAXIFS:

=IF(MAXIFS(tblSchedule[Date],tblSchedule[Public Speaker],[@Name])=0,"",MAXIFS(tblSchedule[Date],tblSchedule[Public Speaker],[@Name])).

Just informational in event someone else needs this information.